# Maven - Scanned from multiple locations warning from the same dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

This is the warning I get:

```
[WARNING] org.apache.fop.accessibility.StructureTreeEventHandler scanned from multiple locations: 
jar:file:///C:/Users/westjjes/.m2/MY_APP/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/2.6/fop-2.6.jar!/org/apache/fop/accessibility/StructureTreeEventHandler.class, 

jar:file:///C:/Users/westjjes/.m2/MY_APP/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop-core/2.6/fop-core-2.6.jar!/org/apache/fop/accessibility/StructureTreeEventHandler.class
```

When I look at my dependency tree this is what I see:
[Dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm9F6.png)

How is this even possible and how do I fix it? I can't exclude fop-core because then my app won't compile.

Comment: that is not maven related, java just tells you the same class is present in two different jars.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Ok, but surely this is a bad thing? So how would I got about fixing it? If there was two non-related dependencies I would just exclude one of them, but I can't do the same here. fop-core is needed by by fop.

Comment: that is how fop.jar was packaged, if you want to avoid such warnings you need to define dependencies on individual modules (`fop-core`, `fop-events`, etc) instead of `fop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is open issue for similar problem: [FOP-3088](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-3088)

One of proposition is:

> Can you reference
>
> ```
> --- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-util:2.6
> --- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-events:2.6
> --- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-core:2.6
> ```
>
> instead of the parent, as the parent is designed for cmd line use outside of mvn

Comment: Yeah, I thankfully managed to figure this out earlier by myself and it seems to work. Thanks for helping! :)